# jqgrid break down single row of data and display in two rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, row

I have a database with a lot of columns (10-15) and I want to be able to display them without the user having to scroll left and right. The optimal solution would be to split the data into two rows, where half of the data would be represented in the first row and the other half of the data would be represented in the second row. For example, I want something that looks like this:

```
    ------------------------------- --------------------
    |   No  | Acct No  |  Name  |  CXN  | VQN | Amount |
       ---      ---       ---      ---    ---     ---
    | Notes | Location | Status |  Sys1 | Sys2|  Sys3  |
     ------- ---------- -------- ------- ----- --------
    |   1   |  453235  |  Item  |  746  | W23 | 455673 |
       ---       ---       ---     ---    ---     --- 
    |  abc  |   34FG   |   None |  112  | 321 |  56C   |
    ----------------------------------------------------
```

The first two rows are headers and the next two rows are an example data set. I looked into an answer to this question: [How to divide one cell into 2 in jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666326/how-to-divide-one-cell-into-2-in-jqgrid) using formatters.

However, the main constraint is that the data must still be sortable and editable inline, and it does not appear that solution will allow these to happen. I also looked into subgrids, but the problem is there is no way to sort the data set on a complete scale. So my question is will what I hope to achieve with splitting the record into two rows yet retaining all the edit/update/sort/etc. functionality of a regular one-row record be possible? Is there a better way of working around this?

Note: it is not necessary that the headers be split as shown. Priority is placed on allowing the data to be properly shown and manipulated.

Comment: Your "optimal" solution is simply not intuitive (have you seen an example anywhere where this is split like this), so I'd suggest you to rethink if it's worth the hassle.