# how modal popup can split into two columns of jq grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqGrid with Add action modal popup, problem is I have huge columns to show pop up so I want to split into two columns, How can I do that..?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666326/how-to-divide-one-cell-into-2-in-jqgrid)

Comment: @shyamnathan This may happen for only jqGrid, but I want to split columns of modal popup window?

Comment: getting width problem for my model popup window, how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `rowpos` and `colpos` properties of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions) in `colModel` to specify position of the column on the Add/Edit form. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MulticolumnEdit.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852741/315935) demonstrate it.

Comment: Working fine, but getting width problem for modal pop up, should show without scroll bar....??

Comment: @Sanjay: You should include `width`, `dataheight` and `height` [option of Add/edit form](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) if it imprives the visibility. For example I used `width: 450` in the referenced demo (just open the source of my demo and search for parameters of `navGrid`).

Comment: Got it..!! Just mentioned in jq grid css file. Thanks @Oleg, you made me so simple to achieve this task.

Comment: @Oleg I would really appreciate if you take a look at my unanswered question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007945/jqgrid-bindkeys-goes-up-to-the-first-invisible-tr). Please advise if my question is not clear. Thank you.

Comment: @onepotato: Sorry, but I don't use keyboard navigation on web sites which I create. I don't use `bindKeys` myself and I played with it only for writing of some answers on stackoverflow. You can read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6170308/315935) which shows how one can **replace** the code of `bindKeys`. You can get the standard code of [bindKeys](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L3777-L3866), include it in your code, debug it and make required modifications. Probably you need change `tabindex` attribute or make changes in the `event.keyCode === 38` part